# SQL pivot with dynamic columns - result

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

Table 1) JOB_129_FEED_ITEMS

| id | SHORT_TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | McGregor Moccasins |
| 2 | Bose speaker |

Table 2) JOB_129_FEED_ITEMS_CLASSICTAX

| id | items_id | CLASSICTAX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FASHION |
| 2 | 1 | CASUAL FOOTWEAR |
| 3 | 1 | FOOTWEAR OTHER |
| 4 | 1 | FOOTWEAR OTHER MEN |
| 5 | 2 | BROWN GOODS |
| 6 | 2 | HIFI |
| 7 | 2 | HIFI LOUDSPEAKERS |
| 8 | 2 | HIFI LOUDSPEAKER |

They can be joined on JOB_129_FEED_ITEMS.ID = JOB_129_FEED_ITEMS_CLASSICTAX.ITEMS_ID

And i am looking for a result like this

| id | short_title | CLASSICTAX1 | CLASSICTAX2 | CLASSICTAX3 | CLASSICTAX4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | McGregor Homie Moccasins | FASHION CASUAL | FOOTWEAR | FOOTWEAR OTHER | FOOTWEAR OTHER MEN |
| 2 | Auna Simpfy Speaker | BROWN GOODS | HIFI | HIFI LOUDSPEAKERS | HIFI LOUDSPEAKER |

How to do this? SQL Pivot? thanks

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Why to do this in SQL? That's a much better task for your application. Just fetch the data with a simple query and let your program show it in the intended form.

Comment: are you sure your desired query is true? it is different from JOB_129_FEED_ITEMS table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT i.id, i.SHORT_TITLE, c.CLASSICTAX,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.id ORDER BY c.CLASSICTAX) rn
    FROM JOB_129_FEED_ITEMS i
    INNER JOIN JOB_129_FEED_ITEMS_CLASSICTAX c
        ON c.items_id = i.id
)

SELECT
    id,
    SHORT_TITLE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CLASSICTAX END) AS CLASSICTAX1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CLASSICTAX END) AS CLASSICTAX2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN CLASSICTAX END) AS CLASSICTAX3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN CLASSICTAX END) AS CLASSICTAX4
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    id,
    SHORT_TITLE
ORDER BY
    id;
```

Answer (score 0):

data

```
CREATE TABLE  Job129FeedItem(
   id          INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,SHORT_TITLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO  Job129FeedItem
(id,SHORT_TITLE) VALUES 
(1,'McGregor Moccasins'),
(2,'Bose speaker');


CREATE TABLE Job129FeedItemsCLASSICTAX(
   id         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,items_id   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,CLASSICTAX VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Job129FeedItemsCLASSICTAX
(id,items_id,CLASSICTAX) VALUES 
(1,1,'FASHION'),
(2,1,'CASUAL FOOTWEAR'),
(3,1,'FOOTWEAR OTHER'),
(4,1,'FOOTWEAR OTHER MEN'),
(5,2,'BROWN GOODS'),
(6,2,'HIFI'),
(7,2,'HIFI LOUDSPEAKERS'),
(8,2,'HIFI LOUDSPEAKER');
```

use `Join`,`Row_number` and `concat` in subquery of pivot and then `Pivot` as follows:

```
select *
from   (select j1.id,
               SHORT_TITLE,
               concat('CLASSICTAX', row_number()
                                      over(
                                        partition by items_id
                                        order by  CLASSICTAX asc))) PivotC,
               CLASSICTAX
        from   Job129FeedItem j1
               join Job129FeedItemsCLASSICTAX j2
                 on j1.id = j2.items_id) src
       pivot ( Max(CLASSICTAX)
             for PivotC in ([CLASSICTAX1],
                            [CLASSICTAX2],
                            [CLASSICTAX3],
                            [CLASSICTAX4]) ) piv
order  by id asc
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iDBxy5aP)